# Test class on a class contained by another class

Tags: unit-test, controller, class

I have to write a test class for an apex class which look like that :

```
public without sharing class HController{

    //public user currentuser{get;set;}
    public Account personContact;

    //public list <Commande__c> commandesTransferees;
    public List<wrapCommande> wrapCommandeList { get; set; }

    private integer transfereesCounter = 0;  //keeps track of the offset
    private integer transfereesList_size = 10; //sets the page size or number of rows
    public integer transfereesTotal_size; //used to show user the total size of the list

    public HController() {
personContact = ExtranetV2_Utils.currentConseillere;

        transfereesTotal_size = [SELECT count() 
                                    FROM Commande__c 
                                    WHERE Statut_de_la_commande__c != 'En cours' 
                                    AND Type_de_commande__c = 'Démonstration' 
                                    AND Conseill_re__c = :personContact.Id];
}

public class wrapCommande {
        public Commande__c comm {get; set;}       
        public String viewUrl { get; set; }

        public wrapCommande(Commande__c comm, String viewUrl) {
            this.comm = comm;
            this.viewUrl = viewUrl;
        }
    }

[etc ....]
}
```

It's not my full code, there is some others methods too.
My problem is that I have my controller HController() AND another class wrapCommande (which contains a method) and I don't see how I can run the class wrapCommande ...
My test pass in the controller but not in that class...

Here is a part of my test class (but I know there are some things missing) :

```
@isTest
private class HControllerTest{

    @isTest static void HControllerTest() {
        ExtranetV2_UtilsTest.CreerEnvironnement();

        HController controller = new HController();

        controller.getCommandesTransferees(); //some methods...
        controller.TransfereesBeginning();
[etc....]
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to call / cover the inner class wrapCommande in your test class.

if that's right, then all you need to do is something like this

```
Commande__c comm = new Commande__c(); // intialize this object with any required fields and insert the record if you want
String viewUrl = ''; // set this to any string value you want to pass
HController.wrapCommande obj1 = new HController.wrapCommande(comm, viewUrl);
controller.wrapCommandeList = new List<HController.wrapCommande>();
objList.add(obj1);
```

Comment: yes it's what I want to do. I understand your answer but I don't know what parameters I have to put in wrapCommande. Do I need to create an sObject Commande__c named comm before ?

Comment: yes, create a record of Commande__c and pass it along with a string variable. I hv updated my answer for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, I also created a List<HController.wrapCommande> objList = new List<HController.wrapCommande>(); and it works ! Thank you again :)